# How to make a class that uses MPMoviePlayerController to play videos from a webserver, without any memory problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I am really struggling to use custom built classes in Objective C. I can make them fine, but as soon as I use them to do something like play a video (using the MPMoviePlayerController class), I run into memory allocation problems. Ive read and re-read Apples own documentation on [memory management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html), Ive gone through various [online tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1), and I have asked and read many questions on here. But I keep getting the same memory allocation problems time and again.

So far Ive been solving my memory problems by moving all my code into the AppDelegate class (I feel like this is not the right thing to do, I dont want to overload my AppDelegate class). All my properties in the AppDelegate class behave like I would expect.

But as soon as I build a class of my own to deal with a particular task, some of the properties get released unexpectedly (all my properties are being declared as strong, but they are still getting released whilst in use). For example a property holding an object that plays a video *gets released while the video is playing*. I don't understand how or why this is happening.

I feel that I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

I have been trying to figure this out for some time now, (see my past questions), but no matter what I do I run into EXC_BAD_ACCESS problems, usually because a property that Ive declared to be strong gets released out of my control, when I dont want it to.

I feel bad for asking such an open ended question, but I feel like Ive exhausted ever other option available to me.

Can someone please show me, from scratch, the correct way to make a class that uses MPMoviePlayerController to play videos from a webserver - but most importantly, show me how to do this where there are absolutely no memory problems, at any point. Nothing gets released unexpectedly, and everything is in memory when I need it to be there (i.e. while the video is still playing).

I am sorry to ask this question, but after several months of struggling with this issue, I don't know what else I can do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use MPMoviePlayerController correctly, you need to decide when you'd like the video to be playing, how to handle showing and hiding the movie player, and when you'd like things to appear.  I'm going to explain one way to do it with a sample project at the end (scroll down for download link).  Feel free to use and modify the project to your liking.

**The most important part** is to declare the `MPMoviePlayerController` as a property of your custom view controller -- or a custom class used within your custom view controller-- and not to explicitly (or implicitly, through dismissing a view controller, etc.) deallocate the custom class, custom view controller, or `MPMoviePlayerController` until you're done with them.

Placing all your code in the app delegate is generally not good design.  You want to spread your code out so it is modular and easily readable.

Start with a basic XCode project with the .xib that comes with it.  Then create a custom view controller (.h for interface, .m for implementation, and .xib file for user interface) by going to `File > New > File`, selecting Cocoa Touch from the left-hand side, and choosing Objective-C class.  Click next, and name the file `MyMovieViewController`.  Check the box "With XIB for user interface".

Now, modify your App Delegate:

In AppDelegate.h, add a property for your custom view controller:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyMovieViewController
    *myMovieViewController;
```

In AppDelegate.m's -application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: function, initialize your custom view controller, and declare a UINavigationController initialized with `MyMovieViewController` as its "root view controller":

```
self.myMovieViewController = [MyMovieViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyMovieViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myMovieViewController];
        self.window.rootViewController = nav;
```

Next, set your application's window's root view controller to this UINavigationController.  declare a UINavigationController initialized with your ViewController as its "root view controller". The last line of the app delegate's function should still read:

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Now, to the good stuff. You now have a custom view controller, `MyMovieViewController`.

In `MyMovieViewController.h`, give it a `MPMoviePlayerController` called `mpController` as a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *mpController;
```

In `MyMovieViewController.m`'s viewDidLoad function, instantiate `mpController`:

```
NSString *urlString =@"...";  //your url here
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
self.mpController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
```

Create two buttons in `MyMovieViewController`'s xib, and link them to -(IBAction)showControllerButtonPressed:(id)sender and -(IBAction)hideControllerButtonPressed:(id)sender, both implemented in the .m file

In -(IBAction)showControllerButtonPressed:(id)sender, add the following:

```
self.mpController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,320); //your size here
[self.view addSubview:self.mpController.view];
[self.mpController prepareToPlay];
[self.mpController play];
```

This sets the correct size, adds the controller's view as a subview of your custom view controller's view, prepares the movie, and plays it.

In -(IBAction)hideControllerButtonPressed:(id)sender, add the following:

```
[self.mpController pause];
[self.mpController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

This pauses the video (so audio and video stop playing) and removes the controller's view from your custom view controller's view.

The property `mpController` will live in `MyMovieViewController` for the life of the program, since you added `MyMovieViewController` as the root view controller of the `UINavigationController` in the AppDelegate.  If you'd like to present and dismiss `MyMovieViewController`, reloading the movie each time, you should set `mpController` = nil when you dismiss.

Note that you can also tell `mpController` to pause and play when the view will appear, disappear, gets backgrounded, etc.

**Here's a sample project** demonstrating the `MPMoviePlayerController` as a property of a custom view controller.  (Note, this project has one more view controller, used to present and dismiss the view controller containing the `MPMoviePlayerController`.  To ensure that memory is being deallocated properly, run the project using Instruments, with the Allocations instrument.  Filter by `ViewController`, `MyMovieViewController`, and `MPMoviePlayerController` to see the relevant classes get allocated and deallocated):

http://www.filedropper.com/examplemovie-xcode5-ios7

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer. It has helped me immensely, particularly the parts concerning the view controllers. Have the well deserved bounty! :)